Can this difference of covariance optimization be represented as convex optimization?
I have 2 estimates of covariance: $\Omega_a$ and $\Omega_b$.
I want to find the vector $x$ that minimizes the following
$x'\Omega_ax - x'\Omega_bx$
subject to
$x>0$ (each element is positive)
$1'x=1$ (sum of elements is 1)
This would be a trivial problem if I wanted to optimize the sum, rather than the difference.
Ideally I could solve this using quadratic programming, since that is what I am familiar with, but if not QP, can it be done with some other more general kind of convex optimization, such as SOCP?

Are you looking for an algorithm or a solution? Do you know whether $\Omega_a-\Omega_b$ is positive semidefinite?

Maybe even more importantly: Is the matrix invertible?

it is not positive semi definite but, based on a simulation I just ran, it does appear to be invertible. I have come up with a method to find some sort of optimization, using constrOptim in R. I note that the result is different depending on the initial value given. So I am starting to suspect this is a non convex problem with multiple local optima.

Does anything stop you from solving the problem numerically?

No, numeric solve is a good enough fallback. More curious to know if this is convex, with a global optimum. Doesn't look as though it is.

If $\Omega_a-\Omega_b$ is not convex, it is not convex. I recommend Matlab‘s fmincon for numerical treatment
